# Load all the classes from specific package

Tags: java-11

I need to retrieve classes from package.
Which Class or interface from Jdk11 could I use to load my classes?

I tried :

Class loader.getSystemClassLoader().getDefinedPackages();

It is not possible to iterate or find method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why do you think you need to retrieve all classes from a package?